# Error `contains` undefined in Google Maps JS API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
function gB(a,b,c){b[rb](function(b){var e="Om"==c?b[gl]():b.get("latLngPosition");e&&!b.pegmanMarker&&a[Vb](e)?rp(c,"-v",b):sp(c,"-v",b)})};
```

It tells me there's an error here.

- Firefox calls it "a is undefined".
- Chrome calls it "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'contains' of undefined"
- Safari calls it "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'a[gb]')"

This is related to markers. After walking through breakpoints:

- The "b" variable is some marker data with `title`, `map`, `position`, etc attributes.
- The "gl" variable is "getPosition".
- The "e" variable ends up evaluating out to a position object (lat/lng).
- The "a" variable is being passed in as undefined, which explains the error.
- The "Vb" variable is "contains", which explains the Chrome error.

Since this is a Google script, I'm wondering if I have something funky going on in my codebase or how to resolve this. Anyone else run into this? What is "a" supposed to be?

---

This is being called from this in `main.js`.

```
ig[E].forEach = function(a) {
    var b = this.va, c;
    for (c in b)
        a[Gc](this, b[c])
};
```

In this code, "a" references the snippet block shown above. So
`a[Gc](this, b[c])` essentially evaluates to `gB.call(this, markerObject);`

Comment: What is your code that is calling the API?

Comment: "This is related to markers." The only thing I do is, 
    `new google.maps.Marker({
        map     : this.map,
        position: this.position,
        title   : this.location.get('name')
    });`

Comment: What [version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) of the API are you using?  Can you provide a jsfiddle or a link that exhibits the error?

Comment: :( ... You just solved it. Just realized I was using the 3.experimental version of the API. That also explains how this error just came out of nowhere too. I went back to 3.13 and it doesn't happen anymore. I guess their experimental markers are broken currently. Definitely an, "oh. my. god. why did i?" moment.

Comment: It might be worth filing a [defect report](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/), however you will have to provide an example that reproduces the problem, but if it is really an error in the experimental version, the examples in the documentation should produce it.

Comment: Example in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sRfFc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because I had been using "3.exp" which is the experimental API. I guess there was an error happening in it and I didn't realize. Switched to production, 3.13, and it fixed the bug. Cheers to [geocodezip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210329/geocodezip) for asking about the API version.

[Defect report](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5798)